# Read info.plist in custom framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, tvos, watchos

I want to read the files contained within the framework info.plist my own creation. When I try to read, the rferans it've read his file info.plist framework applications.

I need to read both. How can I do it? Could you help?

```
NSLog(@"*** %@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedInfoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ASD"]);
NSLog(@"*** %@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ASD"]);
NSLog(@"*** %@", [[[[NSBundle allFrameworks] objectAtIndex:0] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"ASD"]);
```

[image: Framework Screenshot]

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: as you need to get this with Path like below:

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"YOURPLISTNAME" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *dictplist =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];`

Answer (score 4):

First create bundle by using your framework path:

```
NSString* mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString* frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFrameworkBundle.bundle"];
frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
```

Then access Info Dictionary or what you want

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers.

Solution are as shown below:

```
[[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"ASD"]
```